# IOS 8 how to post messages, images on facebook, Twitter community page

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

IOS 7, 8 how to post messages, images on Facebook, Twitter community page's wall. I tried with SLComposeViewController and it is possible to post in logged in user's wall but didn't see how to post to a Facebook or Twitter community or page wall.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Make an attempt and come back here with specific questions. "Write my code for me" is not an acceptable question.

Comment: 'SLComposeViewController *faceBookPost = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    
    [faceBookPost setInitialText:text];
    [faceBookPost addImage:image];
    [faceBookPost addURL:url];
    
    [faceBookPost setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch (result) {
        }
    }];

Comment: their is no post to community is their

Comment: Consider taking your code out of the comment and make an edit to your post with proper formatting for readability.

Comment: please tell me whether the iOS facebook sdk support for post to community wall. If not not what i have to use.

Comment: [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{page-id}/feed"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
How we will give the {page-id}/feed

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with UIActivityViewController.Create a button outlet And write the below code in IBAction.

```
- (IBAction)Share:(id)sender{


 NSString *shareString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Write here what you want to share"];


    NSArray * itemsArray = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",shareString]];//if you want to share image here pass url of image in the array.

    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
    UIActivityViewController * AVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsArray applicationActivities:applicationActivities];


    [self presentViewController:AVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    [AVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL done)
     {

         NSString *ServiceMsg = nil;

         if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
             ServiceMsg = @"Mail sent!";
         } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
             ServiceMsg = @"Shared on twitter!";
         } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
             ServiceMsg = @"Shared on facebook!";
         } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
             ServiceMsg = @"SMS sent!";
         } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]) {
             ServiceMsg = @"Added to Reading List";
         } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard]){
             ServiceMsg = @"Link Copied";
         }

         if ( done )
         {
             UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ServiceMsg message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [Alert show];

         }
     }];

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks , This is not the context. In this we are allowing user to pick the default social logins available. I want to post the messages directly to some community page wall without launching a facebook app .

Comment: Explain your question properly

Comment: I wan't to post text, image to Facebook or Twitter Community page (eg: facebook.com\digitalcare,  facebook.com\GE etc) and the messages will be posted on the community wall. From my native app i will be having UI for entering the text and selecting image and on post button click the content shoul be posted on public pages.  i tried with SLComposeViewController and it's limited only 3 API's image, text , addurl  on loged in user wall. We can't post on public pages wall. For that we need to explore Facebook SDK  and graph API i think. I think u got my point.